# おでこ vs ひたい - is there any difference?

Tags: word-choice

おでこ vs ひたい - is there any difference?

Both show as having the same meaning so I am wondering which to use.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is in the formality.

「おでこ」 is informal, colloquial and conversational.

「額{ひたい}」, by comparison, is slightly more formal than 「おでこ」.

Both mean "***forehead***" and in most people's daily lives, 「おでこ」 is probably used more often than 「額」.  In my life, at least, I say and hear 「おでこ」 considerably more often.

Which one to use would totally depend on the occasion and the speaker.  If you have a specific situation in mind, please let us know.

Additional Info:  You do not have to know this, but 「でこ」 in 「おでこ」 originally means "***protrusion***" and 「お」 is the honorific 「お」.

Answer (score 1):

They have a little difference nuances. [Wikipedia(Japanese)](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A1%8D) says :

> くだけた言い方でおでこ（でこ）<sup>[[1]](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A1%8D#cite_note-1)</sup>

Anyway, ひたい(額) is formal. おでこ is informal.